# Why does tensorflow pause for 3 minutes after "successfully opened the dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Why does tensorflow have 3 minutes pause between "Successfully opened the dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1" and "Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix"?

The related code(incomplete):

```py
from keras.models import Sequential

cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, padding="same",activation="relu",input_shape=(43, 1)))
cnn.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))
cnn.add(Convolution1D(128, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
cnn.add(Convolution1D(128, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))
cnn.add(LSTM(lstm_output_size))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.1))
cnn.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

cnn.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The Output result:

```
2021-04-20 17:03:43.689454: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-04-20 17:03:43.690115: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-04-20 17:03:43.690774: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-04-20 17:03:43.690807: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-04-20 17:06:41.297456: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-04-20 17:06:41.297566: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-04-20 17:06:41.297574: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
```

Conda environment:

- python=3.7.10
- cudatoolkit=10.1.243
- cudnn=7.6.5
- tensorflow-gpu=2.4.1

Hardware:

- Intel® Core™ i5-7200U
- GeForce 940MX

Comment: According to Tensorflow documentation `CUDA 11.0`, `cudNN 8.0` are compatible for `TF 2.4`, either you can upgrade CUDA and cuDNN accordingly or just simply downgrade your `tensorflow version to 2.3`. For more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). Thanks!

Comment: I tried it, but on conda of linux, tensorflow-gpu=2.4.1, cudnn=7.6 and cudatoolkit=10.1 are bound together and I can’t change it.

Comment: It's an issue with conda, you can log a issue [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues). Thanks!